# NSUserDefault not Saving If Followed by a Delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, delegates, nsuserdefaults

I am finding that if I execute a custom delegate method right after saving to NSUserDefaults, the data is not saved and the following error is displayed:

***The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10875.)***

The above error shows under iOS 8 but does NOT show under iOS 7.  However, the results (the data not saving) is common to both versions.  iOS 7 just doesn't show an error has occurred.  Also, this is running on a simulator.

This issue only occurs when I call a custom delegate after writing the data.  If I remove the custom delegate, the data is written with no issues.

The code is as follows:

```
[self.prefs setObject:self.secondsLabel.text forKey:@"timer"];
[self.prefs setInteger:self.questionTypeControl.selectedSegmentIndex forKey:@"type"];
[self.prefs setBool:self.speedSwitch.on forKey:@"speed"];
[self.prefs setBool:self.mixupSwitch.on forKey:@"switch"];
[self.prefs synchronize];

[self._delegate setupStatus:configChanged withVC:self];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

As "synchronize" returns a BOOL I did do a check and did find that it was returning TRUE so the data should be saved, but again it is not.  If I comment out the delegate line, the data is saved appropriately.

The delegate is firing a method in the prior VC.  I put a breakpoint on the first line of that method but the error had already occurred.  This makes me believe that the issue is simply the act of calling the method.  Of interest, if instead of using a delegate I use an NSNotification, the problem doesn't present itself.

Why would calling a delegate cause the error and the inability to save the data?

Update: I did run it on an actual device (iPad running iOS 8.1).  I still get the exact same error as mentioned above, however, the data DOES actually save.  So the sim and device produce the same error but on the sim it won't save and on the device it will.  Again this is only if the delegate is present.

Comment: 1.  Why naming _delegate? (The under score). 2.  In the setupStatus method, if you comment out all the code to see if merely calling the delegate gives you the problem?

Comment: Regarding the delegate, that is just my naming convention here.  I have put a breakpoint on the very first line of the delegate method as mentioned and the issue does still occur.  So it is not anything the method itself is doing.  Just calling the delegate is enough to cause the problem.